# Illegal argument for datetime pattern in App Inventor 2

Tags: android, mysql, datetime, app-inventor

I'm using a smartphone to save daily reports to database (Mysql), using App Inventor 2.
When i try my Apps using all type of Samsung Smartphone, it shows Error like this.[Samsung notification Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyzPe.jpg)

This is the notification Error :

"Sorry to be so picky Illegal argument for pattern in Clock.FormatDateTime. **Acceptable patterns are empty string, MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss a, or MMM d, yyyy HH:mm.** The empty string will provide the default format, which is "MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss a" for FormatDateTime, "MMM d, yyyy" for FormatDate. To see all possible pattern, see docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/… END APPLICATION"

But when I use Xiaomi A1, no error notification appears. And the data can smoothly insert to Database.
This is the datetime pattern that i use in Block script.
[Block Pattern Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svC3R.jpg)

[image]

I'm using "**yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**" clock pattern in App Inventor 2.

Comment: Please post the actual code you have so far. Do not post images of your code - they are less easily searchable.

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question itself, not to the comment section

Comment: what happens, if you use one odf the suggested datetime paterns? For all possible patterns, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: i've tried using "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss". It can't insert to mysql. Maybe mysql can only accept this "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem. By using procedure that join "yyyy","MMMM","dd", and "HH:mm:ss".

[Block Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH7dR.jpg)
[image]

Comment: what about using only one pattern rather than joining 4 different ones?

Answer (score 0):

To do it easily you just have to do the following

InstantInTime MakeInstant(text from): 
Returns an instant specified by MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss or MM/dd/YYYY or hh:mm. An example text input is "06/22/2015 12:18"